# How do I reformat this to add php inside php?

Tags: php, conditional-content

I currently use this conditional code...

```
<?php
if ( $paged < 2 ) echo 'some text';
else echo 'some other text';
?>
```

I need to add some more php between the 'if' and 'else'...

```
<p>Text...<?php $published_posts = wp_count_posts('item'); echo $published_posts->publish; ?> text... <?php echo do_shortcode("[count]"); ?> text.</p>
```

...so that it'll be something like this...

```
<?php
if ( $paged < 2 ) echo 'some text';
<p>Text...<?php $published_posts = wp_count_posts('item'); echo $published_posts->publish; ?> text... <?php echo do_shortcode("[count]"); ?> text.</p>

else echo 'some other text';
?>
```

That obviously won't work, but I don't know enough to recode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [As PHP documentation says](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)
>
> Often you'd want to have more than one statement to be executed conditionally. Of course, there's no need to wrap each statement with an if clause. Instead, you can group several statements into a statement group.

So You have to use `curly braces` `{}` to add more statement within `if` `else`

```
<?php if ( $paged < 2 ) {
echo 'some text';
?>
<p>
    Text...
    <?php $published_posts = wp_count_posts('item');
    echo $published_posts->publish; ?>
    text...
    <?php echo do_shortcode("[count]"); ?>
    text.
</p>
<?php
} else {
  echo 'some other text'; 
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix and the link - which helps me better understand. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ( $paged < 2 ) :

    echo 'some text';

    $published_posts = wp_count_posts( 'item' );

    printf( "<p>%s%s%s%s%s</p>",

        'Text...',

        isset( $published_posts->publish ) ? $published_posts->publish : '',

        'text...',

        do_shortcode( "[count]" ),

        'text...' );

else :

    ?>some other text<?php

endif; ?>
```

You can use any combination of functions that gets the job done and helps you see what you're doing effectively.

```
<?php if ( 2 > $paged ) :

    ?>some text<?php

    $published_posts = wp_count_posts( 'item' );

    printf ( "<p>%s%s%s%s%s</p>",

            'Text...',

            isset( $published_posts->publish ) ? $published_posts->publish : '',

            'text...',

            do_shortcode( "[count]" ),

            'text...' );

else :

    echo implode( PHP_EOL, array (
        'some',
        'other',
        'text',
    ) );

endif; ?>
```

> - [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)
> - [`if... else..`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp)
> - [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)
> - [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)
> - [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)
> - [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)
> - [`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol)
> - [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

If your nesting get really out of hand, it might make more sense to create partials that can be [included](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/06/wordpress-include-template-files.html).

```
include TEMPLATEPATH . '/template-name.php';

load_template( TEMPLATEPATH . '/template-name.php' );

locate_template( $template_names, $load );

include( get_query_template( 'template-name' ) );

get_template_part( $slug, $name );
```

> - [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)
> - [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
> - [`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)
> - [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)
> - [`load_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_template/)
> - [`locate_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/)
> - [`get_query_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_template/)
> - [`get_template_part`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

WordPress does have some [coding standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/) you can follow or utilize with other tools like CodeSniffer as [Standards](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards).

```
# check

phpcs --standard=WordPress

# fix

phpcbf --standard=WordPress
```

Comment: @jgraup...Thanks. Your solution is more complex than I can currently grasp, so I'll read the comprehensive links so I can better understand. ;-)